# Union and intersection of $F_\sigma$ sets

Tags: general-topology, analysis

A set $A ⊆ R$ is called an $F_\sigma$ set if it can be written as the
countable union of closed sets. A set $B ⊆ R$ is called a $G_δ$ set if it can be
written as the countable intersection of open sets.

How to prove, that:

1. The countable union of $F_σ$ sets is an $F_σ$ set.
2. The finite intersection of $F_σ$ sets is an $F_σ$ set.

Thanks for help!

Comment: What is $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}F_\sigma $ written out?

Comment: The first claim is obvious since countable union of countable unions of closed sets is again a countable union of closed sets (union is associative). For the second claim, [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/F-Sigma_Sets_Closed_under_Intersection) and finite induction does the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $P_n, n \in \mathbb{N}$ are $F_\sigma$ sets so we can write $$P_n = \bigcup_{m \in \mathbb{N}} F_{n,m},\text{ with } F_{n,m} \text{ closed in} X$$

But then $$\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} P_n = \bigcup_{(n,m) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}} F_{n,m}$$

and the union is also a countable (as $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is countable) union of closed sets, hence an $F_\sigma$.

Also $$P_1 \cap P_2 = \bigcup_{(n,m) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}} (F_{1,n} \cap F_{2,m})$$

(check this identity), so the intersection of two $F_\sigma$'s is an $F_\sigma$ again, and by induction we can extend this to all finite intersections in the standard way, or alternatively use that

$$\bigcap_{i=1}^k P_i = \bigcup_{f \in \mathbb{N}^k} \bigcap_{n=1}^k F_{n,f(n)}$$ as a generalisation of the previous identity.

Comment: Can i argue in the same way, that countable intersection of $F_\sigma$ sets is an $F_\sigma$ set?

Comment: @Ronald, no because the countable intersection involves the union of continuum many intersections if we write it in the same way: $\bigcap_n P_n = \bigcup_{f \in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}} \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} F_{n, f(n)}$. We need infinite sequences of integers instead of finite ones and that makes a big difference.

Comment: @Ronald and one can show there are $(F_\sigma)_\delta$ sets that are not $F_\sigma$, but this gets tricky. Believe it: it's is false. A whole theory called "descriptive set theory" has been developed for such questions. See e.g. the book by Kechris of that title if you really want to know more about this.

Comment: Thanks, you really help me!!

Comment: @Ronald glad you've been helped. You're welcome.